# How to delete duplicates based on condition on 2 columns using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have following table. I want to delete duplicate rows and keep the one that has Name1 = Name2. So, in the example below row 2 and 4 should be removed.

```
ID | Name1 | Name2
 1 | n1    |  n1
 1 | n1    |  n2
 2 | n1    |  n1
 2 | n1    |  n2
```

How can I do this with SQL query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
delete from t
    where t.name1 <> t.name2 and
          exists (select 1
                  from t t2 
                  where t2.id = t.id and
                        t2.name1 = t2.name2
                 );
```

If you just want a `select`, that can be done similarly:

```
    select t.*
    from t
    where t.name1 = t.name2 or
          not exists (select 1
                      from t t2 
                      where t2.id = t.id and
                            t2.name1 = t2.name2
                     );
```

Comment: Thanks ! This works but can I  ask you a related question here?